# target jQuery variable with differing class

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables

UPDATE- You can see the workings of this [here](http://2harris.holdenandyou.com/).

I'm trying to slim down this jQuery but don't know how to use the following variable to target various child elements.

```
var country = $('#global-map li');
```

As you can see above, I've created a variable for `#global-map li`. Each of these list items has a different class and I want to target child `a` elements within each.

I've not managed to do it and have resorted to the following but I'd like to know the correct way for doing this.

```
    $('#global-map li.map-europe a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                country.removeClass('map-active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('map-active');
                globalSlider.royalSlider('goTo', 0);
            });
            $('#global-map li.map-usa a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                country.removeClass('map-active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('map-active');
                globalSlider.royalSlider('goTo', 1);
            });
... etc
```

I *think* I could even create an array for the different classes in order to write the code once instead of every time for each class. Something like this:

```
var mapArr = ["europe", "usa", "china", "australia", "brazil"];
```

then utilise that with some kind of +1 for the line:

```
globalSlider.royalSlider('goTo', slide+1);
```

Comment: It looks like `globalSlider.royalSlider('goTo', VARIABLE)` is the only class dependent part of all this code, but you do not provide enough information for us to even know what that is. Could you do so please?

Answer (score 0):

I would add the attribute data-target to the anchors:

This way you could have something like

```
<a data-target="1">
```

or

```
<a data-target="china">
```

then

```
$('#global-map li.map-europe a').click(function(e){
    globalSlider.royalSlider('goTo', $(this).attr('data-target'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what I would do:

```
$('#global-map li a').click
(
    function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        country.removeClass('map-active');//BTW Where is country instanciate?
        switch($(this).parent().attr('class'))
        {
            case 'map-europe':
                globalSlider.royalSlider('goTo', 0);
            break;
            case 'map-usa':
                globalSlider.royalSlider('goTo', 1);
            break;
        }
        $(this).parent().addClass('map-active');
    }
);
```